# iOS 8 - Changing permissions manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-location

I am developing an application for iOS 8.1.2 and i make requirement permission to `CLLocationManager`, but if the user does not accept permission and go to panel settings and try to change the privacy settings, the settings close at the time of selection (like a crash) and if user return in the settings panel , it is still selected the "Never" option.

Problem: As much as you try to change this permission it will never change. It happens to the application in the background or completely inactive.

> **My Problem not in code to get location and not in code to request information. Is in the change permission of my**
>   **application on device.**

Comment: What version of iOS 8 are you on? 8.0, 8.1, 8.1.2?

Comment: @Gian have you got solution ?

Comment: I had similar problem with a third party app on my phone, it resolved itself after restart of the device, that is why I think it is a iOS issue.

Comment: even after restart, to not solved...